My Misleading PhD Application Experience
This is just my personal experience, and not everyone will go through the same thing. After completing my Master's degree, I decided to apply for a PhD program. I began the application process and reached out to several professors. This story is about one of the professors with whom I had a Zoom meeting. We spoke that year for about an hour and a half on a weekend, according to the U.S. time zone. The conversation was excellent, with many questions asked and answered. The professor explained that many people apply, around 70-80 applicants, and only three to five are selected. He asked me questions about myself, my understanding of cultural differences, and whether I thought I might experience culture shock, and what might cause it for me. Most of the questions from his side were about this. I also asked questions about access to information since I would be coming from outside the U.S. Unfortunately, I found out later that the university required official documents, but I only had provisional ones at the time, and they didn't accept my application. I informed the professor that I would probably apply again next year, and he was supportive and encouraged me. I won’t deny that I was impressed and really wanted to work with him because our research interests were so aligned. Moreover, very few professors work in this particular field.
The following year, I emailed him again, informing him that I would apply with my official documents. He responded, assuring me that he would do his best. He emphasized again that the program was heavily committee-driven, which he had mentioned during our previous conversations as well. I didn’t doubt this because the program's website also stated that decisions were made by a committee. I knew that in some universities, professors have more power, while in others, the committee plays a bigger role. After submitting my application, during the months of waiting, I came across a post on Reddit where someone shared a link to the university's statistics, showing the number of applicants, acceptance rates, and their GPA for all departments. I checked my field and was shocked by the discrepancy in the numbers. The year I spoke with the professor, the number of applicants never even reached 70; it was around 50...30 applicants... And contrary to what the professor had said, seven students were accepted in one year, and in the year I couldn’t apply, six were accepted. Additionally, the average GPA of accepted students was quite low, even though the program’s website said that lower scores were still acceptable. I became suspicious, but I kept it in the back of my mind and moved on.
When I finally received my decision, I was rejected. I emailed the professor, asking for the reason, and he said the competition was tough. He gave me some numbers again, saying that 90 people applied that year. He said he defended my application, but the committee made the decision. I thanked him and mentioned that maybe my documents were weak. He replied, saying it was just the competition. However, I still had doubts because of the conflicting data. I told myself that if I wanted to find out the truth, I should investigate the 90 applicants claim. Initially, I decided to let it go, but I couldn’t stop thinking about it since I had worked so hard to get my official documents and apply. So, I sent an email from a fake account to the program director, expressing my interest in the program and asking whether a professor's support could still result in rejection by the committee. The director's response surprised me even more and confirmed my suspicions that the professor had been misleading me all along. The director explained that admissions were based on the professors' funding, and if a professor supported you, the committee would usually approve after a review. He said that most students who were accepted had followed this route. Essentially, the professor had a lot of power, especially if they had funding. The professor had told me during our meeting that the funding for students came from the program itself, and when I asked again, he confirmed this. I didn’t doubt him because I had seen that a couple of other universities where I had met with professors clearly stated on their websites that the program offered full funding.
What the professor never mentioned and completely concealed was the fact that if he didn’t have funding, he couldn’t accept a student at all. To be 100% sure, I asked the director how many people had applied that year and how many were accepted. He told me that around 60 people applied, and they accepted five. The only thing I did was to send the information the director provided to the professor using my main email account. I was furious because by telling me that the competition was high and the committee was the decision-maker (aside from all the false information he had provided), he had indirectly told me that I wasn’t good enough for the program and that my resume wasn’t competitive enough, even though he claimed he had tried his best and the committee rejected me.
I contacted the director again from my main email, explaining my situation, and asked what my exact weakness was. The director replied that the professor didn’t have funding, and that was why I was rejected. He also apologized for the situation. When I sent this data and pointed out the discrepancies to the professor, his only response was to say that the number I provided, i.e., 90 applicants, was normal and tried to justify it, even though the university’s data and the director’s statements were clear. Finally, in his last sentence, he admitted that he didn’t have any funding.
Looking back at our meeting and the questions he asked me, I can now see some red flags, but at the time, I trusted him—what else could I do? He was a professor I genuinely wanted to work with. I could have picked up on certain things from his Google Scholar page as well, like the fact that he had published very few papers, and there were huge gaps between them. However, we can't judge solely based on this because some professors focus on other aspects of their work. But even if his intentions were good, he should have told me the truth. He had been at the university for 33 years, so it’s impossible that he didn’t know how things worked and what the process was like.
How could you I identified the red flags earlier, and what advice would you give others to spot them in similar situations?
It's was ok to have 90 minutes meeting?
What do you think motivated the professor to mislead me?
To the professor, if you ever see this post: You were not worth the effort or the honesty I showed throughout this process. I just wish I understood why you did this to me and what your goal was.
He is a professor in urban planning at one of the top ten universities in this field.
How should I proceed?

Welcome to the site. It sounds like a very complicated experience. However, this site is specifically for Q&A, not general sharing of experiences.  Do you have a question that the community could answer?

Not the place to rant. And you are being unfair to a supportive person

@nateEldredge Thanks I added some
Is it ok to have 90 minutes meeting? My other meetings were never that long...

@Buffy in what way? And how?

‘It's was ok to have 90 minutes meeting?’ Yes it was.

"He had been at the university for 33 years, so it’s impossible that he didn’t know how things worked and what the process was like." From experience, that is not impossible in the least.

Not impossible but very rare... likely zero ...when you're in the committee for several years...he knew the true reason of rejection he knew the process...

You are making a lot of assumptions and implying the worst.

The problem with this kind of questions is exactly what @Buffy mentions, making too many assumptions and implying the worst or that some foul play is involved, and we only have one side of the story, and were not present at any interactions, so it is easy to be misled by rejection (pain), people here are trying to give you advice to move on, and you should do that,

Ok but you're checking this every minute like you are interested...as you say you're not please don't leave any comments here

I have moved on and just shared my experience nothing else...I don't want others to experience what I went through

You’ve asked for help from others. Gratitude for their comments, whether you agree with them or not, is appropriate and civil.

Let it go.
You didn't get into a program and that hurts. The professor in question was somewhat disingenuous, and didn't want to directly give you a hard rejection.
The difference between 30, 40, 50, or 90 applicants is immaterial, especially in a live conversation working on memory. Likewise the difference between 5, 6, or 7 acceptances is completely irrelevant. None of this is worth spending any thought on, to say nothing of an extended cloak-and-dagger investigation.
Find another positive prospect and pursue that instead.

It was the hardest rejection I have ever got in my life...I think being honest about the funding situation was the best thing he could do

I've added an answerable question at the end of your post and will try to answer that...
I seldom answer "questions" that I've voted to close and I seldom respond in detail to rants, but I'll make an exception. This is too long for a comment stream, though it might well be deleted.
First the answer and then comments on your rant. I'll assume you want a path to success and will try to give an outline.
If you want to get accepted into a doctoral program you first need to understand and comply with the rules and processes of the place you apply to. These vary widely in the world, but in the US the standard (not universal) is to apply to an admissions committee. Individual professors not on the committee may have no say whatever in the outcome, even if they would like someone admitted. And, even when on the committee, only have one vote and must still consider balance and fairness based on application materials. See the various answers to the canonical question on doctoral admissions for detail on the various standards.
Next, cast a broad net for programs. Don't apply to just a few and don't apply to only similar institutions. If you cast a narrow net, being rejected by one is (somewhat) correlated with being rejected by other similar places.
Next, note that competition is fierce in some fields, but I don't know about yours specifically. If the field is small with only a few relevant institutions the competition can be fierce even with small numbers.
Next, note that if 60 apply and 5 are accepted (not especially unusual) then 55 people are in your same situation.
Next, make your application stronger if possible. In the US that means, to a large extent, getting very strong letters of recommendation from those who know you and your work well and can honestly attest to your likelihood of success in the program and in the career.
Your statement of purpose should also contain the appropriate things, being forward looking. What (sub) field are you interested in, which suggestions for possible research if you have that. Also, career goals are useful to include. Don't repeat the CV and don't give excuses for anything lacking or negative.

To respond to the rant. I think you are being unfair to this professor. They tried to be helpful and in your own words they were  honest with you. They said the acceptance was up to a committee. They spent time with you, which not everyone is willing to do. They may have no say in the process and, as in some places, it might have been improper to intervene if they aren't on the committee. In some, but not all places, a professor can have some influence, but there is no reason to blame them specifically if they don't. And, even committee members seldom get a decisive vote, though practice varies.
It is also common in many (most?) fields in the US, that professors don't provide funding. The funding comes from the department or the university, often in the form of a Teaching Assistantship, or possibly (rarer) a Research Assistantship. But that funding is independent (normally) of the question of acceptance into the program. In some fields (math, CS) nearly every accepted student gets a TA since there is a huge need to support the undergraduate program in the field. That may or may not be the case in urban planning. Funding is probably harder in fields that don't have a corresponding large undergraduate program and likely depend on grants, which can be difficult to get (and maintain).
Your comments about funding and what you describe as the professor's statements suggest to me that the professor might just be new (to the application process) and not familiar, yet, with how things work in that department. What they describe is common, as I note here, but not universal.
It isn't surprising that the professor didn't have accurate numbers about applicants if they were not on the admissions committee. I never had such information and might be guessing based on random comments from colleagues ("Darn, we're flooded this cycle..."). It would take time and effort to eke that out and the numbers change.
I'm sorry you are frustrated, but you need to stop blaming others and up your game. If you do that you can find success. But if you exude anger always then few will want to work with you.

He was on the committee and is...he wasn't transparent about the process and wrote ...I found the funding problem after rejection not from Prof but from the director

I know funding from uni is common but the it wasn't the case in that uni and he knew that from the beginning... And you're really biased ...I had the right to know the truth...

Rage is not a superpower. Effectiveness is. Find a path with more likelihood of success.

I just shared my experience and asked some questions... that's all
